# This simple comparison of jQuery objects does not compare

Tags: javascript, jquery

Curious what I'm doing wrong here :

```
employee_ids = $('[data-employee_id="'+employee+'"]');
timestamp_ids = $('[data-scheduled_on="'+timestamp+'"]');

var common = $.grep(timestamp_ids, function(element) {
  $.each(employee_ids, function(idx, item) {
     if ( item === element ) { console.log ("omg!") };
  });
});
```

This returns just the list of `timestamp_ids` and not that array compared against `employee_ids` looking for a single match.

Comment: two jQuery objects will never be equivalent. compare the DOM elements instead. `if (item === element) { console.log ("omg!") };`

Comment: Fair enough. Then it returns the list of `timestamp_ids` and does not compare against `employee_ids`

Comment: shouldnt the function passed to grep return bool?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to grep down to? what do your two arrays look like?

Comment: Both arrays are an array of `td` elements. There should be just one with the exact `employee_id` and an exact `timestamp`. So I'm trying to get down to just a return of a single `td`.

Comment: @Trip so you have two data points, `employee_id` and `timestamp`, and you are trying to find a `td` that matches BOTH of these points?

Comment: Yes that is correct, jbabey :)

Comment: @Trip in that case grep is probably not the best approach. i will update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using [.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) correctly. Each iteration of grep should return a boolean: true to add it to the result array, false to ignore it.

```
var listA = [1, 2, 3];
var listB = [2, 3, 4];

var union = $.grep(listA, function (element) {
    return listB.indexOf(element) !== -1;
});
```

Note that IE does not support `.indexOf` on Arrays, you will have to implement the comparison some other way.

EDIT: if you are trying to find a single item of an array that matches some criteria, i would suggest just using a regular for loop:

```
var result;
for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    if (yourArray[i].id === employee_ID) { // whatever conditions you have
        result = yourArray[i];
        break;
    }
}

if (result) {
    // do whatever
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Comment: jBabey, thanks so much for your help. Check out my answer below as well. I think it takes the cake on being only one line :D

Comment: @Trip yeah, jquery attribute selectors are really powerful. good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever else is wrong with that, it looks like the error is happening at `$.grep`

What is the typeof of timestamp_ids? According to the [jQ docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), it needs to be an array.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
employee_ids = $('[data-employee_id="'+employee+'"]');
timestamp_ids = $('[data-scheduled_on="'+timestamp+'"]');

var common = $.grep(timestamp_ids, function(element) {    
    return !($.inArray(element, timestamp_ids) == -1)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoa! Thanks for everyone's help. I just realized I could do this :

```
$('[data-employee_id="'+employee+'"][data-scheduled_on="'+timestamp+'"]');
```

I also realized I'm an idiot :(